# How to represent Real Numbers in Binary in VHDL

Tags: floating-point, binary, vhdl

I want to know how I can represent real numbers (including floating points) in binary format in VHDL.

For example: represent +0.5 or -0.013 in binary

I want to program a function in VHDL that can take an input (for eg. 0.5) and increment it by 0.15 until it reaches 10. All the numbers need to be represented in binary form.

I also need to know how to convert the binary numbers back into their real equivalent (decimal)

Comment: Worth adding the precision and range you require : full IEEE P754 single or double precision? Or how many bits of exponent and mantissa do you need? There are synthesisable fixed and floating point packages available : do either of these meet your needs?

Comment: I need a precision of 3 decimal places. In binary I would like to allocate 1 bit for the sign (+ve or -ve), 3 bits for the integer component and 8 bits for the floating component (mantissa). Can you please give me the names of the synthesisable packages that you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Floating point packages for VHDL are here - http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/

But the resolution and range you have decided on with your 12-bit FP format could be accommodated (more simply and with greater accuracy) in a 17-bit fixed point number (scaled integer) so I would suggest that instead.